# Box2D - How to make a hollow circle

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, geometry, box2d

I would like to know how to make a hollow circle, with boxes and distance joint, something like this:

[image: Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [subirimagenes.com](http://s2.subirimagenes.com/otros/previo/thump_6122929circle.jpg))</sub>

I've tried it but I cant get a perfect circle, any idea? thanks

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Can you also specify what language/port you're using?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one route.
Draw a regular *n*-gon. Below, the blue is a regular 16-gon.
Then translate each edge outward radially, and connect each
translated (red) edge to its original (blue):

---

[image: CircleRects]

---